# Nodejs mongoose improvement of update player function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a logic that updates a specific player when he log out of the game, however I would like to know how can I improve it to (ex: check and compare data before update). So right now here's what is happening when a player log out:

```
var updateData = { //data to comapre - save
    experience: player.experience,
    money: player.money,
    last_planet: player.last_planet,
    last_ip: player.last_ip
};

userModel.savePlayerProgress(player.username, updateData)
.then((res) => { if (!res) return; //make sure we actually have result
    console.log(`Logout: Player ${player.username} saved`) //notify
}).catch(err => console.log(`Logout: Saving player ${player.username} failed with error: ${err}`)); //handle issues
```

And here is how savePlayerProgress works:

```
function savePlayerProgress(username, data) {
return userModel.updateMany({username:username}, {
    $set: data
});
```

}

So what I was mean with check and compare data before update is that currently the logic behind it is to update all the data for that player, but for example the player money may be the same as they was when he logged in and in this case the money doesn't need to be updated. Now it's easy to do something like:

```
userModel.savePlayerProgress(player.username)
.then((res) => {
if (player.money != res.money) {
//logic for saving player money
}
});
```

But it will get very very nested and complicated in the future because eventually I will have to compare and save lots of information for each player, so I am looking for the best/fastest way of doing this. Thank you.